# Freeze multiple columns in html table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table and my goal is to be able to freeze the first 3 columns of my table. This includes the `thead th`with a `colspan = 3` attribute.

The table looks like this:

```
|----colspan: 3------|--------------colspan: n----------------------|
|------|––----|------|--------------n columns-----------------------|
```

I have seen a few replies to fix the first column, but no satisfactory solution to fix the first 2 or 3 columns, or more generally to fix the first n columns, even more so when colspan are involved.

Could it be done in pure html/css? Do I need to use nested tables?

Thanks already!

Comment: Once I implemented this but I dont have source now, but I would say better go with plugins like datatables etc, there is so much hidden complexity in this in different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use `colspan=""` and `rowspan=""`

are you meaning something like this?

```
<table width="700" border="2" margin="auto" align="center" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="10"> 
  <tbody align="center"> 
    <tr> 
      <th colspan="4">Are you meaning something like this?</th> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
      <td rowspan="5" valign="top">123<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br></td>
      <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">123456789<br>1<br>2<br>3<br></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
      <td>123</td> 
      <td>123</td> 
      <td>123</td> 
    </tr> 
  </tbody> 
</table>
```

**[DEMO Here](http://jsfiddle.net/T5gjP/)**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it's not what I need. I need to freeze the left columns, ie the table is horizontally scrollable but first columns stay in place.